# How to Extend Relaxation Methods for 2D Laplace Equation given in Jackson E&M to 3D?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

In Jackson (3 ed) chapter 1.13 an outline is given for using relaxation to solve laplace equation in 2D. The general procedure in 3D involves minimizing the quantity

$$I[\Psi]=\frac{1}{2}\int_V \nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\psi d^3x $$

But in 2D they seem to use the surface integral over an area A. This leads to equation 1.76 where the integration is taken over the north east corner of a box of dimension h x h

$$I_{NE}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{h/2}dx\int_0^{h/2}dy\bigg [\bigg (\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\bigg )^2+(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\bigg )^2\bigg ] $$

The approximation to the derivatives in the north east corner is given by the potential of the neighboring grid points

$$\bigg(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\bigg )_{NE}=\frac{1}{h}(\psi_o-\psi_E)$$
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\bigg )_{NE}=\frac{1}{h}(\psi_o-\psi_N)$$

Where $\psi_N$ is the grid point north of the center grid point $\psi_o$ and so on. Putting these approximations into the integral and integrating gives 
$$I_{NE}=\frac{1}{8}[(\psi_N-\psi_o)^2+(\psi_E-\psi_o)^2]$$.

Now I try to do the same thing in 3D starting with

$$I_{NE+}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{h/2}dx\int_0^{h/2}dy\int_0^{h/2}dz\bigg [\bigg (\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\bigg )^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\bigg )^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}\bigg )^2\bigg ] $$

where the + denotes the point above $\psi_o$ in the z direction. I can make approximations similar to those above and I get

$$I_{NE+}=\frac{1}{16}h[(\psi_N-\psi_o)^2+(\psi_E-\psi_o)^2+(\psi_+-\psi_o)^2]$$

Here I have units of length times potential squared so I am a little concerned that I may have missed something. Could someone verify that this approach is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2D you are going to get an extra factor of $1/h$ that you can't get rid of. It's because in 2D you have in some sense line charges with units of $[Charge]/[Length]$, and similarly with field units. So when you discretize (and, by the way, your discretization is only first order accurate in space) you're going to have this units problem for lower than three dimensions. In two dimensions, you have line charges, and in one dimension you have sheet charges. Hence, your units of electrostatic potential have to change to match the change in the units of your charges.